# Creating Second JS App Not Linked to First (Same Code, SharePoint Online)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I have a small JS app shown in the below code. It runs in SharePoint Online and connects to a short list to cycle between a Red, Yellow, or Green "status". I'm not sure what to change in order to keep it "separate" from a second app, doing exactly the same thing but with a different title/meaning. Currently, I created a second list named something different and changed the URL line to point to that list, but the web part displays black as shown below.

```js
<div id="production-planning-btnPopover" class="pp-container" style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="This content gets replaced" data-placement="bottom">Production Planning Status<i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Info" id="pp-status-icon"></i></div>

<script>
(function(){
        var call = $.ajax({
            url: "https://MYCOMPANY.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Production%20Planning')/items?$select=Status&$filter=Title%20eq%20\'Current%20Status\'",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        });
        call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
         var ppStatus = data.d.results[0].Status;
         if(ppStatus == "Green"){
          $("#production-planning-btnPopover").addClass("pp-green");
          $("#production-planning-btnPopover").click(function(){
           $(".popover-title").text("Milwaukee DC On Schedule for On-Time Completion");
           $(".popover-content").text("Enter orders as normal.");
          });
         } else if(ppStatus == "Yellow"){
          $("#production-planning-btnPopover").addClass("pp-yellow");
          $("#production-planning-btnPopover").click(function(){
           $(".popover-title").text("DC Near Capacity");
           $(".popover-content").text("Continue to enter orders as normal however if you have an order larger than 10,000 in quantity contact the Milwaukee OCN so the DC can provide you with realistic ship dates based on your customer's demand.");
          });
         } else {
          $("#production-planning-btnPopover").addClass("pp-red");
          $("#production-planning-btnPopover").click(function(){
           $(".popover-title").text("DC At Capacity");
           $(".popover-content").text("DC is currently at or beyond capacity. Try to schedule orders at other DC locations. If you cannot, contact OCN so the DC can provide you with realistic ship dates based on your customer's demand.");
          });
         }
        });
        call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
            alert("Error retrieving list data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
        });
})();
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    //did not click a popover toggle or popover
    if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover'
        && $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0) { 
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhkMM.png)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean about 'keep it "separate" from a second app'?

In SharePoint hosted add-in, we can create two client web part to show content separately.

If the lists in app, we need use the code below to get the appweburl.

```
 appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
```

More information about creating a SharePoint hosted add-in with REST API for your reference:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/58e23e/sharepoint-hosted-app-using-rest-api-from-client-side-script/